# Volume slider - volume doesn't change until mouse over

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, flash, flash-cs3

I've created a small music player with a sliding volume control.  I'm having trouble with the volume.  Though it does control volume properly, if I set the initial volume to less than 100%, the volume always starts at 100% until I move my mouse over the player.  At that point, the volume changes to whatever the initial volume is set to.

Is this a flash bug, or am I missing something?

Here is the affected code (code for other buttons/functions omitted for brevity):

```
var song_initvolume:Number = 100;
slider_1._x = groove_1._x + song_initvolume;
playSong(0,song_play);

slider_1.onPress = function() {
    this.startDrag(true, groove_1._x, groove_1._y, groove_1._x + 96, groove_1._y);
}

slider_1.onRelease = function() {
    this.stopDrag();
}

slider_1.onMouseMove = function(){
    newPoint = new Object();
    newPoint.x = this._x;
    newPoint.y = this._y;
    groove_1.globalToLocal(newPoint);
    mySound_sound.setVolume(-1 * newPoint.x);
}

function playSong(songNum,songPlay,reset_Pos){
    if(reset_Pos){
        mySound_sound = new Sound();
    }
    var myTitle = mySongs_array[songNum].TITLE;
    trace("Playing TITLE= " + myTitle);
    var myArtist = mySongs_array[songNum].ARTIST;
    trace("Playing ARTIST= " + myArtist);
    var myURL = mySongs_array[songNum].URL;
    trace("Playing URL= " + myURL);

    title_txt.text = mySongs_array[songNum].TITLE;
    artist_txt.text = mySongs_array[songNum].ARTIST;
    mySound_sound.loadSound(myURL,songPlay);

    // start oncomplete
    mySound_sound.onSoundComplete = function() {
    song_pos = 0;
    reset_Pos = true;

    if(song_continuous){
        song_play = true;
        current_song++;
        if (current_song>=my_total){
            current_song=0;
            if(song_loop){
                song_play = true;
            } else {
                song_play = false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        song_play = false;
    }
    playSong(current_song,song_play,reset_Pos);
}

    // end oncomplete
    }
```

I'd like to be able to set the volume at say 50%, but the above mentioned behavior happens each time.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call mySound_sound.setVolume() with your initial value.  Right now you only do in in the onMouseMove handler.

Comment: Should have mentioned that I had that code in there as well & I had the same symptom.

Up top, I had:
var song_volume:Number = 50;

then, before the song plays for the first time, these lines:
song_volume = -1 * song_volume;
mySound_sound.setVolume(song_volume);

No worky!

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed with this code:

```
mySound_sound.onLoad = function(){
    mySound_sound.setVolume(-1 * song_volume);
}
```

Works great now!